# In Function Point Analysis How is organization Productivity calculated?

Tags: project-management, function-points

In function point analysis how is organization productivity calculated?

Thanks 
SC

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you don't calculate but measure it.

You should be measuring your project and organization velocity (function points, or any other unit related to size, delivered in a unit of time). Iterative+incremental or agile processes are good here since the measured velocity from previous iterations or sprints can be used to estimate upcoming iterations or sprints. The shorter the iterations or sprints, the better you will be able to learn and fine-tune your estimates.

Eventually it will boil down to balancing between predictability and flexibility.

When starting you don't yet have any historical data. Then you'll just have to base your estimate on educated guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Function Points delivered per unit time.

For each deliverable, define the function points.  Measure the effort.  Divide.